# Как сохранить спрайт в Qt?

Tags: qt, спрайт

Есть спрайт.Я хочу повернуть и сохранить в новый спрайт с прозрачным фоном (альфа = 0) или можно не сохранять но работать с повернутым на прозрачном фоне. Может как то через QPixmap?

Comment: попробуйте конкретизировать вопрос. и укажите хотя бы язык...